# Where do I find Mindstorms building plans?

Tags: mindstorms

I have the Mindstorms NXT 1 kit. It includes a printout of the first robot model building plans. The plans for several other robots (e.g. the scorpion bot) are included in the NXT software. However when I run the software, everything works, but it does not display the building instructions, only the programming instructions. Can I download those plans somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official building instructions for NXT 1 models can be downloaded here: http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/buildinginstructions/8527-/T-56.aspx

Comment: The above link now forwards to https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms?domainredir=mindstorms.lego.com which is the product page for the EV3.

Answer (score 1):

You can get almost every building instruction [directly from lego](http://us.service.lego.com/en-US/BuildingInstructions/default.aspx) - just type in the set number.

For `8527` (which seems to be your set) there are 7 downloads available (note: I'm not sure if the ones you're looking for are contained, because I don't know the set - but they should be there).

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately that link only supplies me with the printouts that where contained in the set (seven downloads for seven languages). What I need are those instructions that are only digitally in the NXT software.

Comment: too bad, sorry. but i'll leave my answer here for future visitors who might look for this.

Answer (score 1):

This link seems to have the original building instructions, Alpha Rex is confirmed.
http://www.learningfun101.com/2013/02/lego-nxt-instructions/

also try

https://manuall.co.uk/toys/lego/lego-mindstorms/