# Where do I get PDF instructions for LEGO builds that were only in software, like NXT as of 2019?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, software, instructions, mac

LEGO Mindstorms NXT 2.0 (8547) stored almost all of its build instructions in the associated software. LEGO no longer supports the software for modern macOS versions. I can not find build instructions for the software-based 8547 builds (the ones not in the instruction booklets). Does anyone know where I can get them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I find Mindstorms building plans?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/916/where-do-i-find-mindstorms-building-plans)

Comment: The question is a duplicate but the answer on question page now links to https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms?domainredir=mindstorms.lego.com which is the product page for EV3

Answer (score 1):

The NXT 2.0 software can be found at https://www.lego.com/nl-nl/themes/mindstorms/downloads although it won't install.
But if you already have the software installed and it stopped working you can find the instructions under this path: `C:\Users\[Username]\Documents\LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT\engine\EditorVIs\Academy Content\activities\instructions`.
In this folder, you'll find all instructions that the software includes as `.jpg` files.

For now, this is the only thing I have for you.
I hope it is what you're looking for.
If you don't have this, let me know which instruction you need.
Maybe I can upload it here.